# C++ | Websocketpp | отправить сообщение при on_tls_init

Tags: c++, websocket, asio

Ниже закомментирован код который должен работать, но выкидывает исключение. Как это исправить? В логе: invalid state

```
static context_ptr on_tls_init(client* c, websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl) {
// establishes a SSL connection
context_ptr ctx = std::make_shared<boost::asio::ssl::context>(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
try {
    ctx->set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds |
        boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2 |
        boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv3 |
        boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
}
catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << "Error in context pointer: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}

//string msg = "Connected!";
//c->send(hdl, msg, websocketpp::frame::opcode::text);

return ctx; }
```

Ошибка:

> websocketpp::exception по адресу памяти 0x00A0F444. invalid state
>   (процесс 27376) завершает работу с кодом 0

Comment: Пожалуйста, покажите сам лог.

Comment: websocketpp::exception по адресу памяти 0x00A0F444. 
invalid state  (процесс 27376) завершает работу с кодом 0.

Comment: Это - запись лога, я же прошу Вас показать сам лог - т.е. некие шаги, которые были сделаны до момента появления данной ошибки. Или никакого лога нет и логом Вы просто назвали то, что увидели в stdout?

Comment: Закомментированные строки кода и вызывают исключение. Без них все работает без проблем. Меня интересует как отправить сообщение при коннекте, единоразово. Вот и всё.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратите внимание на порядок вызова ф-ий установления SSL соединения и непосредственно создания соединения. Не могу сказать, что Ваша ошибка заключается именно в этом, но сообщение

> invalid state

говорит о нечто похожем.

```
#include <websocketpp/config/asio_client.hpp>
#include <websocketpp/client.hpp>

#include <iostream>

typedef websocketpp::client<websocketpp::config::asio_tls_client> client;
typedef std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ssl::context> context_ptr;
using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1;
using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_2;
using websocketpp::lib::bind;

typedef websocketpp::config::asio_client::message_type::ptr message_ptr;


void on_message(client* c, websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl, message_ptr msg) 
{
    std::cout << "on_message called with hdl: " << hdl.lock().get()
              << " and message: " << msg->get_payload()
              << std::endl;


    websocketpp::lib::error_code ec;

    c->send(hdl, msg->get_payload(), msg->get_opcode(), ec);
    if (ec) 
    {
        std::cout << "Echo failed because: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
    }
}

static context_ptr on_tls_init() 
{
    // establishes a SSL connection
    context_ptr ctx = std::make_shared<boost::asio::ssl::context>(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);

    try 
    {
        ctx->set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds |
                         boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2 |
                         boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv3 |
                         boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
    }
    catch (std::exception &e) 
    {
        std::cout << "Error in context pointer: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return ctx;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    client c;

    std::string uri = "wss://localhost";

    if (argc == 2) { uri = argv[1]; }

    try 
    {
        c.set_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::all);
        c.clear_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::frame_payload);

        c.init_asio();
        c.set_tls_init_handler(bind(&on_tls_init));


        c.set_message_handler(bind(&on_message,&c,::_1,::_2));

        websocketpp::lib::error_code ec;
        client::connection_ptr con = c.get_connection(uri, ec);
        if (ec) 
        {
            std::cout << "could not create connection because: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }

        c.connect(con);
        c.run();
    } 
    catch (websocketpp::exception const & e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Больше информации [здесь](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/issues/706).

UPD: отправка сообщения

```
c.connect(con);

// std::async т.к. отправляем до того, как запускаем IO сервис
auto future = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]()
{
     std::this_thread::sleep_for(3s);
     con->send("Hi!");
});

c.run();
future.get();
```

Из хэндлера можно убрать эту часть:

```
c->send(hdl, msg->get_payload(), msg->get_opcode(), ec);
```

Comment: Я так и не получил ответа на свой вопрос. Я не знаю как отправить сообщение при коннекте.

Comment: @XeroxLaser, покажите Ваш исходный код.

Comment: Код был взят ранее из источника, который вы приложили

Comment: @XeroxLaser, ок, тогда отправляйте сообщение после вызова `c.connect(...)`.

Comment: @XeroxLaser, обновил.

Comment: Благодарю! Всё работает.

Comment: @XeroxLaser, рад помочь!